# Change output directory of tsconfig

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get Rails5 + Angular2 project (that is deployable to Heroku) up and running.

I've cloned the Angular2 seed project in my rails application and both run fine. A few guides advice to create a symlink between the root (rails) public folder and the (angular) client\dist\prod folder, so that Rails will call that index file and bootstraps the Angular project.

But I'm running into problems with the symlink. Locally it works fine, I can push it to git but on deployment to Heroku I get an error that the public folder already exists.

So I was thinking, why not just change the output directory of TypeScript? But I can't find any info if that's possible. Any tips?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at your tsconfig.json file. :)

Comment: There's no reference to a `dist\prod` folder and on the TypeScript page I can find things such a outDir, if I use `"outDir": "public", create a folder called `public` in the client root folder ` and run `npm start` nothing happens.

Comment: well, it might be set in some build script somewhere. for more help you'd have to share more information of your setup.

Comment: I thought tsconfig is the build script. //edit. Hm tsconfig does call gulpfile.ts, maybe I can do something there.

Comment: tsconfig.json is a file that usually stores the options for tsc. if you use gulp there are plugins that allows you to define the options in the build script too. :)

Comment: What project did you cloned from github? this one https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed ?

Comment: This one > https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed

Comment: Did you try to change this line to your desired output (dist) path? https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/blob/master/tools/config/seed.config.ts#L223

Answer (score 0):

With some tips I've figured out what's going on. In the `seeds.tasks.json` file there are a few "actions", such as `build.dev` and `build.prod`. In those actions are calls to tasks in the gulpfile.

This set up creates 2 different folders. A production and a develop folder. The develop folder works great on the npm server, but Rails can't handle it. Rails can only handle the production folder. And that one has to be build to reflect the changes made in the TypeScript code.

I've created a "move.files" call in my `seeds.task.json` file, which calls a task in my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('move.files', [], function() {
  console.log('moving files');
  gulp.src("dist/prod/**/*")
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../public'));
});
```

So now when I run `npm run build.prod` it builds the Angular2 project and copies to folder to the root public folder of rails to show the changes made.

The problem is that the building proces takes about 10-15 seconds, so building the Angular project on every change is foolish. I think I'm going to develop on the npm server and then "merge" the production output with with the public rails folder when I'm done.